# "Entity framework SQL Script generation failed" error occurs while publishing on azure using SQLite Database

Tags: asp.net, azure, entity-framework, sqlite, visual-studio-2019

I found a lot of questions similar to my problem on MSDN and SF but none of them helped me or maybe I didn't understand them. I'm getting the following error while I'm trying to publish my app on Azure.

> Entity framework SQL Script generation failed

I'm using the SQLite database here. Point to be noted that everything is ok in my local machine. The app runs fine.

I already ran these commands on package manager console - `Add-Migration -Initial` and `Update-Database`

**Publishing setting**

[image]

> In this photo, I entered "Initial" as the connection string in the EF Migrations field. The result is the same. Maybe the problem causing here I guess.

**appsetting.json**

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "EmployeeDB": "Data Source=employeedb.db;"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this could help you if you got an Azure App Service running. I had been searching so long for fix this issue. I was able to resolve the issue using Server Explorer from the Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition.

Before you start, you need to deploy your app *without* migrations, deselect Entity Framework Migrations on your Publish Profile settings, and then publish your Azure profile.

1. On Visual Studio Community 2019, log into your Azure Account under <kbd>Server Explorer</kbd> -> <kbd>Azure</kbd>
2. Select <kbd>App Service</kbd> and double-click on <kbd>Open Cloud Explorer</kbd>
3. A new tab window appears and you'll need to find your Azure Subscription
4. Within your Azure Subscription, you'll see all your App Services
5. Within one, go to the <kbd>Files</kbd> folder and you´ll see all of your deployed files
6. Right click on the <kbd>Files</kbd> folder and select <kbd>Upload File</kbd>
7. Upload your `.db` file in this window

[image: Server Explorer is usually at left toolbar]

[image: This where you can find your deployed files]

Answer (score 6):

For me, this error went away when I checked the Apply this migration on publish checkbox under the Entity Framework Migration options in the publish menu.

[image]

For some reason it was failing to run on its own and my migrations were probably out of sync but I was getting this weird error message in the question above.

Hope this helps anyone that has this issue in the future.

Comment: Saved the whole day, what a hero. Thanks

Comment: For me, "Apply this migration on publish" was ALREADY checked. However, it takes Visual Studio a few seconds to "refresh" the "Entity Framework Migrations" section and the process of doing this seems to re-generate and self-fix things. So after I clicked "Save" and tried "Publish" again, it worked just fine!

Answer (score 0):

OK, after being frustrated at the lack of help online for this error, I *FINALLY* figured out a proper way to debug this error.

FIRST, try Western Reserve Care Solutions' answer. That might be a quick fix for you.

If that DOESN'T work, go to the "Output" window. Near the bottom just above the "Entity framework SQL Script generation failed" error you should see "Executing command" and something like this:

```
dotnet ef migrations script --no-build --idempotent --configuration Staging --output "C:\dev\ClientName\Select\Select\obj\Staging\net7.0-windows\PubTmp\EFSQLScripts\Select.Data.ApplicationDbContext.sql" --context Select.Data.ApplicationDbContext
```

This is your KEY to unlock the error! Now go to Tools->Command Line->Developer Command Prompt. Type "CD solution_name" to make sure you are in the same folder as the *.csproj (in my case that would be "CD Select"). Then copy and paste the KEY COMMAND (the one from YOUR Output window). You are basically manually running the command that Publish tried to do. Except, if there's any error, it will be displayed right there for you in the window!

In my particular case, it turned out to be a runtime bug in the startup code of my web server. Apparently "dotnet ef" needs to run a portion of your code in order to figure out the migrations. I thought my code was tested and working, but what happened was I changed from "Debug" profile to "Staging" as per my Publish procedure, and the bug was specific to the Staging profile. Running the KEY COMMAND from the command prompt highlighted the error right away, showing the full call stack. (Too bad the VS2022 "Publish" command doesn't parse and recopy that output, instead it just dies with cryptic errors.)

Anyway, this should be the life saver you need!

Answer (score 0):

I hope it helps someone but in My case I received an "Entity framework SQL Script generation failed" error.

This was due to me using an InMemory database when trying to publish to production using web deploy.